# Zend static cache - different site skins/designs

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching

I have a site which is using zend static cache and it works great. However, the site also uses the TERAWURFL library to detect mobile devices and show a stripped down version of the site. The problem now is that because the cache gets created for the normal site, this is also output to the mobile devices.

My idea is to use a htaccess device detection to detect a mobile device and deal with the request appropriately. Then inside my bootstrap, I would also check for a mobile device and change the cache path.

My problem is, I don't think there is a good way of doing this. For example, removing cache entries would need to be done on both cache's but the current implementation won't do this.

Has anyone got experience in implementing this kind of cache on different layouts/designs?

I guess this would also apply to languages where the content would have to change.

Comment: Which cache class are you using from Zend?

Comment: Backend: Static. Front end: Page.

Comment: Ok, I've never used Zend's static cache mechanism as I am still primarily running a (slightly) older version of the framework which doesn't even have that class. If you plan on going the .htaccess route then this is going to be tricky. Sorry. I will continue reading and searching for solutions in the meantime, though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When WURFL detects that the user is on a mobile device, set it to a cookie. Then use

```
make_id_with_cookie_variables
```

option of the Zend_Frontend_Page (as specified here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html#zend.cache.frontends.page).

This way it will generate a new id for the page cache thus not conflicting the two versions (regular/wurfl-ed)

Edit: Some mobile devices might not support cookies though. Don't know. You could give it a try though.

Comment: The Static backend uses htaccess to serve a cached version of the whole page with no PHP interaction so this isn't viable. Thanks though

Comment: You are right. So I guess you should add something like SetEnvIf User-Agent "identifier" mobile_device and check for that afterwards.  However if it is not absolutely necessary you could try instead of static to use APC or memcached instead. (Might be even better)